# Summing of columns in one raw - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm making a java app using Hibernate ORM with postgresql.
In database, I have a table of 80 columns of integers. In my app, I want to sum all this columns of one raw. (or let's say 15-30 columns or any other range)

How can I do it effectively? 
I loaded one raw through criteria into object, but I dont know how to sum it better if not writing something like this:
sum += column1; sum += column2; sum += column3..... sum += column80;

Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it via HQL which would look something like

```
select sum(col1 + col2 + col3 + ... + colN) from entity 
where foo = :bar
```